# Is background tasks the solution for this problem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, ios, background

I need to develop an enterprise app that monitors the network traffic. Basically it detects if the user is in wi-fi or cellular data and save the amount of bytes was sent and received in a period of time.
I saw an App at the AppStore that do exactly this job.
Detecting wi-fi or cellular data is quite simple using the Reachability Sample provided by Apple.
My problem is to keep monitoring the bytes sent and received while the app is in background.

As it is an enterprise App, I used UIBackgroundModes "voip" to avoid the app to be terminated.
I also installed the setKeepAliveTimeout method and I'm able to see the logs each 10 minutes, BUT only for 10 seconds after the method runs. I mean, setKeepAliveTimeout brings my App to run a Timer for 10 seconds each 1o minutes.

I'm thinking wether or not a task in background is the best solution for my problem.

I'll appreciate any comments.

EDIT: Ok guys. Thats the perfect way to do it.

First of all you must read this:
 http://www.christian-fries.de/blog/files/tag-ios.html

I tried this and it works really fine.
All we need to do is to create a second thread detached from the main one. This way we have a continuos threading running forever. You must see the GCD docs at Apple's website also.

Second thing you should consider for an enterprise App is to set it up as a voip App, this way iOS will put your App running even after a reboot. It's a special behavior iOS has to keep voip Apps running.

Thats it guys.
I hope it can help you.

Comment: I really would like to know the companies name, so that I never start to work there... Anyway — technical very interesting: +1

Comment: You don't have much of a choice, background tasking with blocks is the only legit way with 4.0+ to execute code.  Were you thinking you could build a service on iOS?  AFAIK You can't do that without Jailbreaking

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Perhaps the app is simply being written to verify the correctness of the bill.  But as for what you are implying, if you work for a company and use their tools, why should you expect privacy?  Do you expect it if you browse the internet with the companies computers?

Comment: @vikingosegundo - thanks to the badge.

Comment: @Peter M — might work for bill checking — for the companies bill and any cell phone bill of guests, private cells, people using the cell on the street in front of the house...

Comment: @slf - Not a service, because I know it's impossible. But maybe someone with experience with this kind of solution could point me to something I didn't realize yet. Anyway, I'll go deeper with the GCD and background tasks. Thanks.

Comment: What app did you see that did exactly this thing you are trying to do?

Comment: @slf - take a look: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dataman-real-time-data-usage/id393282873?mt=8#

Answer (score 2):

We dont have access to this data. There is no way to measure traffic.

The app you saw made an estimation (eg. 1mb/min) and after applicationWillEnterForeground. then you calc time x estimated-traffic and there we go.

Unfortunately there is no way to measure,
 so I did a traffic-reset in settings and then i streamed exactly 1 min music. after a few repetitions I had my results. The problem is, that this works only fine with static traffic-processes like audio or video.

hope could help
endo

**EDIT: look answer below!**

Comment: Permits me to say you're wrong. There is a way to measure and I did it! You are able to check each network interface (lo, en0, pdp_ip0, etc...). The system keeps with all the information about that interfaces inside a struct and we can check to see what values we have inside this struct.
Google for "getifaddrs" and "struct ifaddrs". You'll sure find information about it.
I did it and it's working fine. 
IMPORTANT: The background solution is only to keep monitoring the interfaces each 1 minute for example.